# Capture (screenshot) of inactive tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Would like to capture image of possibly inactive tab.

Problem is that when using the approach displayed here the tab often does not get time to load before capture is done, resulting in failure.

The `chrome.tabs.update()` call-back is executed before the tab can be captured.

I have also tried to add listeners to events like `tabs.onActivated` and `tabs.onHighlighted` and doing the capture when those are fired, but the result is the same. And, as a given by that, I have also tried `highlighted` instead of `active` on `chrome.tabs.update()` – and combination of both; with listeners and call-backs.

The only way to make it work partially better is by using `setTimeout()` , but that is very hackish, not reliable and ugly. The fact one have to activate a tab before capture is somewhat *noisy* – but if one have to add delays the issue becomes somewhat worse.

This is more like a convenience feature for my extension, but would be nice to make it work.

```
/* Not the real code, but the same logic. */

var request_tab = 25,
    request_win = 123
    old_tab;

/* Check which tab is active in requested window. */
chrome.tabs.query({
    active   : true,
    windowId : request_win
}, function (re) {

    old_tab = re[0].id;

    if (old_tab !== request_tab) {
        /* Requested tab is inactive. */
        /* Activate requested tab.    */
        chrome.tabs.update(request_tab, {
            active: true
        }, function () {     
            /* Request capture */                          /* CB TOO SOON! */
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(request_window, {
                format : 'png'
            }, function (data) {
                /* ... data ...  */

                /* Put back old tab */
                chrome.tabs.update(old_tab, {
                    active: true
                });
            })
        });
    } else {
        /* Requested tab is active. */
        /* Request capture. */
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(request_window, {
            format : 'png'
        }, function (data) {
            /* ... data ...  */
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since that you are updating the tab using the `chrome.tabs.update()` method, the callback will be called as soon as the tab properties are changed, but, obviously, **before the page is loaded**. To work around this you should **remember that the tab isn't yet ready** and, using the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event, **check when it's ready** and you can **use `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()`**.

Here is the solution:

```
var request_tab = 25,
    request_win = 123,
    waiting = false,
    // ^^^ Variable used to check if tab has loaded
    old_tab;

// Check which tab is active in requested window.
chrome.tabs.query({
    active   : true,
    windowId : request_win
}, function (re) {

    old_tab = re[0].id;

    if (old_tab !== request_tab) {
        // Requested tab is inactive
        // Activate requested tab
        chrome.tabs.update(request_tab, { active: true });    

        // Tab isn't ready, you can't capture yet
        // Set waiting = true and wait...
        waiting = true;

    } else {
        // Requested tab is active
        // Request capture
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(request_window, {
            format : 'png'
        }, function (data) {
            // Elaborate data...
        })
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID, info, tab) {

    // If the tab wasn't ready (waiting is true)
    // Then check if it's now ready and, if so, capture
    if (waiting && tab.status == "complete" && tab.id == request_tab) {

        // Now you can capture the tab
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(request_window, {
            format : 'png'
        }, function (data) {

            // Elaborate data...

            // Put back old tab
            // And set waiting back to false
            chrome.tabs.update(old_tab, { active: true });
            waiting = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for input. I have listeners on all tab-events and the only one fired are `onActivated` and `onHighlighted`. There is no `onUpdated` event fired. The status for the tab (by `tabs.get()` or `tabs.query()`) both show status as "complete" etc. I can not reload the page.

Comment: You also say *"Since that you are updating the tab using the `chrome.tabs.update()` […]"* – are there other ways of doing this? (Beside asking the user to do it ... :P)

Comment: @user3342816 AFAIK, there aren't other ways to make a tab active. By the way uhm, I don't know if you can catch some event that tells you the tab is ready to be captured... I'm looking for a solution in the documentation...

Comment: @user3342816 nope, sorry, I can't find any listener that can tell you if the tab is ready for being captured... looks like the timeout is the only solution (even if I hope it isn't)... :\

Comment: Yes, I've tried to find any other event queue that I could spy on and various other things, but no luck. Thank you very much for your time on this. I've implemented a solution with timers and counter for max retries. It works good enough, though it does not look to nice.

Comment: If you update answer with a note about timer being (seemingly?) only solution for capture of inactive tab, as we discussed here in comments, I can set it as accepted. As it stands now it do not quite address the issue, it is an important note about capturing after loaded, but that is something that I already have covered. Issue is capture of inactive loaded tabs.